# Match substring but not an exceptional substring

Tags: ruby, regex

I have strings like:

```
new_account_notification
updated_account_notification
reactivated_account_notification
updated_billing_info_notification
```

I want to match these strings as such:

- should contain `account`
- but should not contain `reactivated_account`
- or should contain `billing_info`

Please suggest a regex to satisfy these conditions.

Comment: Which regex flavor do you use ?

Comment: @Alex: I am trying out in my Ruby program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this pattern:

```
(?<!reactivated_)account|billing_info
```

`(?<!...)` is a negative lookbehind (hope your regex flavor support it)

`|` stands for OR

Comment: this would also match if there's no `account`

Comment: @Anirudh: Yes but i believe that it is what he wants.

Comment: @Anirudh: It didn't. I tried to match it on `test_notification` string.

Comment: @Vishal it would match the string `hello world billing_info`..That string doesn't contain `account`!

Comment: Also, to show that it works with Ruby as requested: [**`link`**](http://rubular.com/r/y9uBHAXk3r)

Comment: +1 ohhh..yes this is correct..i thought op wanted `account` as well in string

Comment: @Anirudh: Thanks for your answer too. And yes, FYI -- I needed either of `account` or `billing_info` but not `reactivated_account` if `account` is present.